# Quoting user profile from other answer

Tags: discussion

When quoting content from another SE question/answer, is it necessary to also reference the user's profile as a separate link?

From [this](https://superuser.com/a/961430/175382) answer:

> Source: [Change comment character in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259865/3536342) by [rafiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3226989/rafiki)

as opposed to this:

> Source: [Change comment character in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259865/3536342)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that it depends on the source of material and the licence that they request you follow.

*Technically*, neither of the above fulfils the requirements of the [cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licence that all content on Stack Exchange is licenced under.

> If supplied, you must provide the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice, a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material.

Personally though, so long as the source is properly attributed by stating that this is from somewhere else and giving attribution, irrespective of whether it is internal or external to the Stack Exchange network, then I don't see why we need to decide on one format or another.

We try and be quite lenient about the format of the attribution, only insisting that where material is used then some form of attribution **is** required.  Doing anything less is effectively plagiarism.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/referencing appears to be much less restrictive than the cc-by-sa licence: "make sure you do all of the following:

    Provide a link to the original page or answer
    Quote only the relevant portion
    Provide the name of the original author
". There is no mention of copyright, licence or disclaimer on the help page ...

Comment: Mmmm. What about that notices Vs. superuser.com/help/referencing????